# 15.10 upgraded to 16.04 and PHP broke

Tags: php, 16.04

I accidentaly upgraded my system instead of just putting the updates on, and not my moodle won't work because PHP is messed up.

It tells me I have unmet dependencies, and problems with PHP5-cli.

```
sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-3.19.0-18 linux-headers-3.19.0-18-generic linux-headers-3.19.0-26
  linux-headers-3.19.0-26-generic linux-headers-3.19.0-30 linux-headers-3.19.0-30-generic
  linux-headers-3.19.0-31 linux-headers-3.19.0-31-generic linux-headers-3.19.0-39
  linux-headers-3.19.0-39-generic linux-headers-3.19.0-42 linux-headers-3.19.0-42-generic
  linux-headers-3.19.0-43 linux-headers-3.19.0-43-generic linux-headers-3.19.0-47
  linux-headers-3.19.0-47-generic linux-headers-3.19.0-49 linux-headers-3.19.0-49-generic
  linux-headers-4.2.0-30 linux-headers-4.2.0-30-generic linux-image-3.19.0-18-generic
  linux-image-3.19.0-26-generic linux-image-3.19.0-30-generic linux-image-3.19.0-31-generic
  linux-image-3.19.0-39-generic linux-image-3.19.0-42-generic linux-image-3.19.0-43-generic
  linux-image-3.19.0-47-generic linux-image-3.19.0-49-generic linux-image-4.2.0-30-generic
  linux-image-extra-3.19.0-18-generic linux-image-extra-3.19.0-26-generic
  linux-image-extra-3.19.0-30-generic linux-image-extra-3.19.0-31-generic
  linux-image-extra-3.19.0-39-generic linux-image-extra-3.19.0-42-generic
  linux-image-extra-3.19.0-43-generic linux-image-extra-3.19.0-47-generic
  linux-image-extra-3.19.0-49-generic linux-image-extra-4.2.0-30-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  pkg-php-tools
Suggested packages:
  dh-make
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libapache2-mod-php5
The following packages will be upgraded:
  pkg-php-tools
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 318 not upgraded.
15 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/38.2 kB of archives.
After this operation, 10.2 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  pkg-php-tools
Install these packages without verification? [y/N] y
(Reading database ... 560010 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing libapache2-mod-php5 (5.6.11+dfsg-1ubuntu3.2) ...
ERROR: Module php5 does not exist!
dpkg: error processing package libapache2-mod-php5 (--remove):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libapache2-mod-php5
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How can I get my php fixed?? I can't seem to get the dependencies fixed.

---

Running `sudo dpkg --configure -a` I get a lot of dependency problems-leaving unconfigured.

`sudo apt-get install -f` I get

```
The following additional packages will be installed:
  pkg-php-tools
Suggested packages:
  dh-make
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libapache2-mod-php5
The following packages will be upgraded:
  pkg-php-tools
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 319 not upgraded.
15 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/38.2 kB of archives.
After this operation, 10.2 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  pkg-php-tools
Install these packages without verification? [y/N] y
(Reading database ... 560010 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing libapache2-mod-php5 (5.6.11+dfsg-1ubuntu3.2) ...
ERROR: Module php5 does not exist!
dpkg: error processing package libapache2-mod-php5 (--remove):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libapache2-mod-php5
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Try these commands - http://blog.bodhizazen.net/linux/apt-get-how-to-fix-very-broken-packages/

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem, I tried to get joomla running by installing the basic LAMP packages just after my upgrade to 16.04 when this started happening.
Could not install any packages and could not remove `libapache2-mod-php5`

> Removing libapache2-mod-php5
>   ERROR: Module php5 does not exist!

After some googleing and head scratching I guessed that the fact that Apache was still using php5 was part of my problem.

I am not sure if this was the correct way to fix the problem but I managed to fix this by doing the following:

```
cd /etc/apache2/mods-enabled
sudo mv php5.conf php5.conf.old
sudo mv php5.load php5.load.old
sudo apt-get purge libapache2-mod-php5
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

This solved it and I can happily install and remove software again.

Maybe someone smarter than me can explain why this worked or present a more elegant/ appropriate solution.

Anyway, I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you no longer have PHP 5 and are running PHP7 .. You may need to update some PHP plugins and files for the new  PHP7. php.ini's are now located at /etc/php/7.0 not /etc/php5 .. You may need to change things in apache or moodle to reflect this change

Comment: I did discover PHP7 instead of 5, but I have 300+ updates that won't install because it doesn't seem to have fully installed PHP7? I can't do anything because of it seems unfinished. It has missing dependencies I can't fix.

Comment: did you try the obligatory commands?  and if so what errors or output did you get? `sudo apt-get update --fix-missing` `sudo dpkg --configure -a` `sudo apt-get install -f`

Comment: output of sudo apt-get install -f is above, Tells me php5 does not exist. I did not try sudo apt-get update --fix-missing. Will try in the morning when I am at the system.

Comment: lol sorry .. yeah .. should  have left out that last command .. like i say .. they are kinda of obligatory .. so it was habit typing them out .. lol

Comment: one more thing you can check .. not sure if it will help .. do you have libapache2-mod-php (newer version for php7 I believe) installed if not .. maybe if that was installed it would stop trying to access libapache2-mod-php5

Comment: It seems all php related, I tried to add the ondrej php repository, but sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php tells me command not found, most likely because PHP is messed up.

Comment: path not found usually means exactly that... most likely that ppa doesn't exist anymore .. I'm not good with  it  and it's risky but I hear you can change your  sources all to the older version (wily) i think and then try to fix the  issue with the older software but ... this can have bad consequences and like I say .. I really can't walk you through it because I'm not really familiar with the process